# How to Using Pagination in oc-api-plugin?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

octobercms plugin:
[oc-api-plugin](https://github.com/octobroid/oc-api-plugin)

I don't know what's missing

I've been trying for a while with no success using API Using Pagination

Below is the program I built

routes.php

```
<?php
Route::group([
    'prefix'    => 'api/v1/sample',
    'namespace' => 'Sh\Sample\Controllers',
], function () {

        Route::get('posts', 'postsAPI@index');
        Route::get('posts/{id}', 'postsAPI@show');
});
```

PostTransformer.php

```
<?php

namespace Sh\Sample\Transformers;
use Octobro\API\Classes\Transformer;
use Sh\Sample\Models\Post;

class PostTransformer extends Transformer
{
    // Related transformer that can be included
    public $availableIncludes = [
        //'entities'
    ];

    // Related transformer that will be included by default
    public $defaultIncludes = [
        //'entities',
    ];

    public function data(Post $item)
    {
        return [
            'id' => (int)$item->id,
            'title' => $item->title,
            'content' => $item->content
        ];
       
    }
}
```

PostsAPI.php

```
<?php namespace Sh\Sample\Controllers;

use Sh\Sample\Models\Post;
use Octobro\API\Classes\ApiController;
use Sh\Sample\Transformers\PostTransformer;

class PostsAPI extends ApiController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $item = Post::get();
        return $this->respondwithCollection($item, new PostTransformer);
    }

    public function show(int $id)
    {
        $item = Post::find($id);
        return $this->respondwithItem($item, new PostTransformer);
    }

}
```

TEST:

GET: http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/sample/posts

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "test11",
            "content": "teste222"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "test222",
            "content": "test222222"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "test333",
            "content": "content333"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "test333",
            "content": "test333"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using Paginator not working

GET: http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/sample/posts?page=1,number=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `respondWithPaginator` method to use pagination.

Ref: [Pagination in oc-api-plugin](https://coderecharge.com/october-cms/october-cms-plugin/how-using-pagination-oc-api-plugin)

```php
class PostsAPI extends ApiController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $postPaginator = Post::paginate();
        return $this->respondWithPaginator($postPaginator, new PostTransformer);
    }
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Nice to hear that!